# jQuery execute if statement only once and unwrap elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a jQuery script that is supposed to make a div have fixed position once the user get into the right location of the page.More than that, the script is adding new html elements to DOM using wrapAll().
The problem is that every time the user scroll to the right place, a new set of html elements are added and in the else statement unwrap() is not working.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
// This function will be executed when the user scrolls the page.
jQuery(window).scroll (function(e) {
    // Get the position of the location where the scroller starts.
    var scroller_anchor = jQuery(".get-started").offset().top;
    // Check if the user has scrolled and the current position is after the scroller start location and if its not already fixed at the top 
    if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() >= scroller_anchor && jQuery('.get-a-quote').css('position') != 'fixed' ) 
    {    // Change the CSS of the scroller to hilight it and fix it at the top of the screen.
        jQuery('.get-a-quote').css({

            'position': 'fixed',
            'top': '0px'
        });
        jQuery('#stiky-btn').wrapAll('<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top"><div class="container"><div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse"><ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"></ul></div></div></nav>');

        // Changing the height of the scroller anchor to that of scroller so that there is no change in the overall height of the page.
        jQuery('.get-started').css('height', '50px');
    } 
    else if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() < scroller_anchor && jQuery('.get-a-quote').css('position') != 'relative') 
    {    // If the user has scrolled back to the location above the scroller anchor place it back into the content.

        // Change the height of the scroller anchor to 0 and now we will be adding the scroller back to the content.
        jQuery('.get-started').css('height', '0px');
        jQuery("#stiky-btn").unwrap();

        // Change the CSS and put it back to its original position.
        jQuery('.get-a-quote').css({
            'position': 'relative'
        });
    }
});
});
```

Any ideas?

[Demo here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/obeJyG)

Comment: Can you post a demo?

Comment: As a side note: as IDs must be unique on document context, you don't need to use `wrapAll()`, `wrap()` is enough

Comment: Updated question with the demo thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this check

```
if($("#stiky-btn").parent('.navbar').length == 0){
   jQuery('#stiky-btn').wrapAll('<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top"><div class="container"><div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse"><ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"></ul></div></div></nav>');
}
```

Comment: Ya, that's a good point! But i guess should be used for unwrapping element instead (or both)

Comment: I have updated the demo but the behavior is istill quite strange to me.